# Extract matching coordinates and index of arrays - python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, intersection

I have this following arrays, each element in a and b is supposed to be associated with Lon and Lat coordinates, a and b are referred to as the ID of the coordinates, the data can include negative float values:

```
a = ['1','2','3','4','5','6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
Lon1 = [2, 2, 5, 7, 1, 8, 2, 4, 7, 1]
Lat1 = [1, 2, 1, -4, 4, 7, 2, 8, 3, 4]

b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f', 'g', 'h']
Lon2 = [2, 7, 1, 8, 4]
Lat2 = [1, -4, 4, 7, 8]
```

I tried different ways to get the result I need such using sets but they iterate over all the values and the result I am interested in is strictly extracting from the first set of arrays Lon1, Lat2 that appear in Lon2, Lat2 while using the element name from a and ignoring b.

The desired results are three new arrays with values:

```
c = ['1','4','5','6','8']
Lon3 = [2, 7, 1, 8, 4]
Lon3 = [1, -4, 4, 7, 8]
```

This is just sample data, I am working with a similar set of 2000 points and I need to extract their ID if their coordinates match a smaller set of points.

I tried searchsorted and I tried creating nested for loops with if lon1 = lon2 then append a new list with a[i], but that doesn't work either. I also tried creating a function that enumerates a and uses b as a set but it only seems to return 5 values and I can visually see in my data that there many.

Comment: Completely unclear question, there is no explanation of the desired result

Comment: Provide at least an example of user input and expected output

Comment: Please post your desired output, and any attempt (code) you have tried to achieve that output

Comment: I get how `c` is derived given `Lon3`, `Lat3` (you have a typo there), etc. but not how `Lon3` and `Lat3` themselves are derived.. Are they just copies of `Lon2` and `Lat2`?

Comment: c is derived based lon2/lat2 intersecting the specific lon1/lat1 so c will take the value of a, lon3/lat3 is = lon2/lat2 intersected with lon1/lat1

Comment: I've clarified this question a lot, please remove the hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) for this:

```
c = []
Lon3 = []
Lat3 = []

cnt = 0
for lo1,la1 in zip(Lon1, Lat1):
    for lo2,la2 in zip(Lon2, Lat2):
        if (lo1 == lo2 and la1 == la2) {
            c.append(a[cnt])
            Lon3.append(lo1)
            Lat3.append(la1)

            break
        }
    cnt++
```

Comment: This works for the example but when I use the bigger set of data it doesn't work. It may be important to note that my data is in float with negative values.

Comment: c is only returning the indices of a not the value of a associated with lon1/lat1

Comment: `c` is already corrected now.